# check unique - laravel

Tags: laravel, function, random, unique

When a user registers, each user receives a seven-digit code stored in the database. Each code must be unique and must not be created a second time.
How can I ensure that each code stored is unique and that no error messages occur when an existing code is created?

Function

```
 $randomstring = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 7);
```

Table

```
Schema::create('invites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('greeting')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: What is the relationship of the seven-digit code to a user? Can a code be used more than once?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `doesntExist` in a while loop:

```
while (true) {
    $randomstring = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 7);
    if (Invite::where('code', $randomstring)->doesntExist()) {
        Invite::create([
            ...
            'code' => $randomstring,
            ...
        ]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your Code if the generated Code exists?

Comment: It just keeps looping and creating new random strings until it creates one that doesn't exist.

Comment: i get a error message: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::doesntExists()

Comment: can I also use: if (Invite::where('url','!=', $randomstring))

Comment: It's `doesntExist()` not `doesntExists()`

Comment: i get the same error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::doesntExist()

Answer (score 0):

Use the `firstOrCreate()` function.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods